# On Click Object Types on Dashboard returns empty white page

Tags: facebook-opengraph

On OpenGraph dashboard when i click on Onjects to view their properties, it shows me a white page (an empty page).

Is it because i made in Graph-API-Explorer to much request for testing the APP? Do we have a limited number of request ?

I tried to create another APP on Facebook and define some Opengraph objects there. Same!!! i can create the object but cant see their properties when im clicking on the object !!!

thanks